# How to replace multiple %tags% in a string with PHP

Tags: php, string, str-replace

What is the best way of replacing a set of short tags in a PHP string, example:

```
$return = "Hello %name%, thank you for your interest in the %product_name%.  %representative_name% will contact you shortly!";
```

Where I would define that %name% is a certain string, from an array or an object such as:

```
$object->name;
$object->product_name;
```

etc..

I know I could run str_replace multiple times on a string, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

str_replace() seems an ideal option if you know the placeholders you intend to replace. This need be run just once not multiple times.

```
$input = "Hello %name%, thank you for your interest in the %product_name%.  %representative_name% will contact you shortly!";

$output = str_replace(
    array('%name%', '%product_name%', '%representative_name%'),
    array($name, $productName, $representativeName),
    $input
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This class should do it:

```
<?php
class MyReplacer{
  function __construct($arr=array()){
    $this->arr=$arr;
  }

  private function replaceCallback($m){
    return isset($this->arr[$m[1]])?$this->arr[$m[1]]:'';
  }

  function get($s){  
    return preg_replace_callback('/%(.*?)%/',array(&$this,'replaceCallback'),$s);
  }

}


$rep= new MyReplacer(array(
    "name"=>"john",
    "age"=>"25"
  ));
$rep->arr['more']='!!!!!';  
echo $rep->get('Hello, %name%(%age%) %notset% %more%');
```

Comment: This seems like a good way of doing it, and is closer to what I was looking for.  I'll need to do some benchmarking to see how this compares to using the str_replace() function.  I have a feeling str_replace() will be faster, but this class may be easier to use in practice.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and shortest option is preg_replace with the 'e' switch

```
$obj = (object) array(
    'foo' => 'FOO',
    'bar' => 'BAR',
    'baz' => 'BAZ',
);

$str = "Hello %foo% and %bar% and %baz%";
echo preg_replace('~%(\w+)%~e', '$obj->$1', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP manual for str_replace:

> If *search* and *replace* are arrays, then
>   **str_replace()** takes a value from each
>   array and uses them to do search and
>   replace on *subject*. If replace has
>   fewer values than search, then an
>   empty string is used for the rest of
>   replacement values. If search is an
>   array and replace is a string, then
>   this replacement string is used for
>   every value of search. The converse
>   would not make sense, though.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php